# google chart text direction

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, column-chart

I'm trying to make Column Chart with google chart.

```
function drawChartEPS(response) {

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

data.addColumn('string', 'Period');


data.addColumn('number', 'Q1');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
data.addColumn({type:'string', role: 'annotation'}, '');


data.addColumn('number', 'Q2');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
data.addColumn({type:'string', role: 'annotation'}, '');


data.addColumn('number', 'Q3');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
data.addColumn({type:'string', role: 'annotation'}, '');


data.addColumn('number', 'Q4');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
data.addColumn({type:'string', role: 'annotation'}, '');

data.addRows(response);

var options = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '80%',
    bar: {groupWidth: "90%", width: "100%", gap: "30%"},

    chartArea:{width:"100%",height:"100%"},

    annotations: {
        highContrast: true,
        style: 'point',
        textStyle: {
            fontName: 'Sans',
            fontSize: 16,
            bold: false,
            italic: false,
            direction:-1,
            slantedText:true,
            slantedTextAngle:90,

            opacity: 1
        }
    },
    legend: {
       position: 'none'
    }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
    document.getElementById('EPSChart'));

chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

And get the result
[google chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDJhw.jpg)

But I need that my chart looks like in this picture [examle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnhq9.jpg)
Can not Change the direction of text on the graphs and add arrows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are no standard config options to change the rotation of the annotations,
but you can change them manually, on the chart's `'ready'` event.

however, you will need to use a `MutationObserver`,
as the chart will rotate them back on any activity,
such as "on hover".

to rotate, add a `transform` attribute to each `<text>` element in the svg.
in the `transform` attribute, use --> `rotate(z x y)`, where...
`z` = the angle of the rotation
`x` = the x coordinate of the element
`y` = the y coordinate of the element

`x` & `y` will already be attributes in the element,
so only need the rotation value, such as  --> `-90`

```
transform="rotate(-90 100 300)"
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  data.addColumn('string', 'Period');


  data.addColumn('number', 'Q1');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
  data.addColumn({type:'string', role: 'annotation'}, '');


  data.addColumn('number', 'Q2');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
  data.addColumn({type:'string', role: 'annotation'}, '');


  data.addColumn('number', 'Q3');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
  data.addColumn({type:'string', role: 'annotation'}, '');


  data.addColumn('number', 'Q4');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
  data.addColumn({type:'string', role: 'annotation'}, '');

  data.addRows([['DEC', 500, 'cyan', '500', 600, 'magenta', '600', 650, 'yellow', '650', 700, 'lime', '700']]);

  var options = {
      width: '100%',
      height: '80%',
      bar: {groupWidth: "90%", width: "100%", gap: "30%"},

      chartArea:{width:"100%",height:"100%"},

      annotations: {
          highContrast: true,
          style: 'point',
          textStyle: {
              fontName: 'Sans',
              fontSize: 16,
              bold: false,
              italic: false,
              direction:-1,
              slantedText:true,
              slantedTextAngle:90,

              opacity: 1
          }
      },
      legend: {
         position: 'none'
      }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('EPSChart')
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
      var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
        if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
          label.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(-90, ' + label.getAttribute('x') + ' ' + label.getAttribute('y') + ')');
        }
      });
    });
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="EPSChart"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help